# Is it possible to edit grub.cfg?

Tags: grub2

I wish to change a menu entry in grub.cfg, for example:

From

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu is wonderful'
```

To

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu is world famous'
```

Comment: Try [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer).

Comment: Its possible but ill-advised, and your changes will get overridden.

Comment: @Mitch I did consider Grub Customizer but there are many users who report having issues with it. One user even lost his ability to boot up the OS.

Comment: @n00b Yup, Grub Customizer just crashed on my first attempt to use it

Comment: @n00b That's true. This tool is really good, but also very dangerous.  @ endolith What was the crashing message?

Answer (score 12):

Edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` instead and run `sudo update-grub` when you are done. This is a more reliable method, otherwise every time you upgrade to a new kernel your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will be overwritten and you will lose your changes.

Or you can use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer). To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: @edwin I did consider Grub Customizer but there are many users who report having issues with it. One user even lost his ability to boot up the OS.

Comment: then use the first method. You can post your `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` if you unsure what lines to change.

Comment: Isn't it rather 40_custom, and 10_linux is for proxy?

Answer (score 2):

**How to do it from an emulator to learn how GRUB works**, without the risk of breaking anything.

- create a Multiboot hello world `main.elf` file. GRUB knows how to boot those files (GRUB also knows how to boot the Linux kernel, even though it is not Multiboot)
- create a `iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file containing:

  ```
  menuentry "main" {
      multiboot /boot/main.elf
  }
  ```

  Place `main.elf` under `iso/boot/`
- Generate an image and run it:

  ```
  grub-mkrescue -o main.img iso
  qemu-system-x86_64 -hda main.img
  ```

This will boot into GRUB, and you will see an entry called `main`.

Now edit `grub.cfg` like `menuentry "newmain"`, and upon a reboot the new option name is `newmain`. So your change would work.

I have posted the exact code for this example at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world

As others said, don't do it in practice, since that is normally an output file and will get overwritten on `update-grub`.

Answer (score -3):

yes you can edit this file /boot/grub/grub.cfg