# How to boot between windows 10 and ubuntu without reboot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox, vmware

My professor has asked me to find a way to install Ubuntu the computers at a lab that already has windows 10 installed. I know that I can dual install both of these OS seamlessly and be able to switch between the two by rebooting and choosing which OS to boot into.

Now my issue is, he wants to allow students in the class to remotely access those computers and be able to switch between the OS as needed. If they have to reboot then they will lose connection and won't be able to chose which OS they want to boot into.

Is there a way for me to make it so that people who remotely access the desktops be able to switch OS without rebooting?

I've looked into VirtualBox and VMware, but with the setup of Windows 10 as a host and Ubuntu as a guest, it doesn't allow VirtualBox to access the gpu of the host. With VMware is the same issue, I can't get the guest to read the gpu of the host instead of the virtual one.

What can I do to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the inverse, ie., Ubuntu as host and Windows 10 as guest?

Comment: My professor wanted to keep Windows 10 as the host. I've read some articles online where I can do what I needed if I did the inverse, but I'm being restricted with having the host be Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that.

If you want to visit your neighbor you have to leave your home and enter his place. You can not be at both places at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635205/link-to-restart-from-windows-to-ubuntu") may be what you are looking for.
- You can also fiddle with GRUB [like so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu), but that is risky when you consider your users skill level.
- There is a [method](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-shortcuts-to-quickly-reboot-to-the-alternate-os-in-a-vistaxp-dual-boot) to create links for swapping Windows version via reboot you might pursue, but since it is Ubuntu on top of Windows 10 I don't believe it will work (GRUB should handle the OS list, not bcd), even knowing the correct replacement values in those scripts.

Each of those are able to be used in a remote connection and allow the connection to be re-established after loading the next OS. One pitfall is they would need to be already loaded into one OS or the other for remote users to have any control. Most remote software allows access to the login screens so once its finished loading up there should be no issue there.

Comment: I believe you mean "GRUB" (the boot loader which Ubuntu uses) and not "grunt" (whatever?)... Edited that. Also please rather use Markdown syntax to format your post instead of HTML.