# Re-install 18.04.3 with dual boot Windows 10, boots to grub prompt. How to get grub recreated and boot to ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

Win/Ubuntu both installed on  my 4th HD - SDD, and after a re-install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 from live cd, I can not get back to Ubuntu.

I use SDA, SDB, SDC as additional hard drives.

I can manually select "Windows" to boot from bios (MSI Mother board) and Win10 boots, however there are 2 other selections there: another Win10 and Ubuntu... both take me to the grub prompt, which I can determine what to do there nor how to fix grub.

Here is my origrinal boot-info report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sFghcwPvtv/
(disregard some of the "old" versions of grub/windows on the other drives, I've swapped hard drives around a bit I guess).

Pertinent parts are below the cut lines.

A few years ago I tried Grub2Win (hence a big part of the mess!), but it seemed to not work after Windows updates so I reverted to the traditional Grub and all was fine.

I then installed boot-repair (I assume it completed the suggestions at the bottom of the initial report) and after it ran, it said there were "Errors":
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/57Hn5BD5cm/
(Pertinent parts are at the bottom)

Is there an easy way to clean all this up (short of nuclear)? or at least get me to a working state?

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd and looks at sector 
    1824911768 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,gpt6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following 
    components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdd2 starts 
                       at sector 923648. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, sdd2 starts at sector 923656.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi 
                       /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /EFI/grub2win/grub2win.boot64.efi 
                       /EFI/grub2win/grub2win.efilevel.124.txt 
                       /EFI/grub2win/grub2win.efirescue.cfg 
                       /EFI/grub2win/grub2win.efisetup.cfg 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi 
                       /boot-repair/log/20181204_003552/sdd2/bootx64.efi

sdd3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda1: unknown filesystem type ''.
mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sdd3: unknown filesystem type ''.

sdd4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdd4 starts 
                       at sector 1161216. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, sdd4 starts at sector 1161240.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdd5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdd7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

----------------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdd2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You have BIOS boot loaders in most drives' MBRs. But as long as you never try to boot in BIOS mode, those will be ignored. You have SFS which is dynamic Windows partitions on sdb, Best to undo those, Microsoft offers no undo, but some third party Windows tools  may. But be sure to have good backup. Do not know grub2win? You should just delete UEFI 0003 entry as that has Windows description but grub boot. No errors on reinstall of grub, but error seems related to sdb drive which will not work with Linux as long as dynamic.

Comment: grub2win is a grub loader with an ability to modify the menu easily in windows.  It is actually a decent idea... just didn't get enough support I imagine.  Looks like it is still supported: https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/ Thanks!

Comment: More info on dynamic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv
 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692248 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1779529 Delete an UEFI entry. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228