# Using different hard drives with different OS

Tags: 18.04, grub2, hard-drive

I am an Ubuntu user.
I want to change hdd with ssd and install windows 7 to it. After using win7 several days, I want to change ssd with old hdd and use ubuntu. 
Is this possible?

I have read that [using ubuntu with win 7 on the same hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) is possible but I do not want it for now.

Actually my only one concern is regarding about grub. After using win7 with ssd and change it with hdd with loaded ubuntu may disrupt grub and ubuntu will not boot ?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? UEFI normally forgets UEFI boot entries. But it also normally finds Windows entries. You have to use efibootmgr from live installer to add new entry & houseclean old entry. If BIOS, it boots from MBR of drive you select so no issue. See `man efibootmgr` and more examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI .

Comment: sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0008
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0008,0002,0005,0004,0003,0006,0007
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002* USB FDD:
Boot0003* ATA HDD: WDC WD7500BPVT-24HXZT3                  
Boot0004* ATAPI CD: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208AB                
Boot0005* USB HDD:
Boot0006* USB CD:
Boot0007* PCI LAN: Realtek PXE B04 D00
Boot0008* ubuntu
------

Comment: When I type "sudo efibootmgr" command ,the result is like above. This means is I am using UEFI ?

So do I change hdd with ssd and install win7 for a while, then change ssd again with old hdd with ubuntu. If ubuntu not booted after returning back to hdd with ubuntu, what should I do? As far as I understand , I have to try live(without installing) ubuntu from usb and install some packages to repair the records regarding grub