# Ubuntu 20.04: error: “symbol not found: ‘grub_efi_secure_boot'”

Tags: grub2, 20.04, boot-repair

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop. It had been previously running 18.04 (mostly) fine. After installing, it just stayed stuck on the GRUB menu and any time I tried to select Ubuntu it would just print that error a few times and return to the menu.

I tried boot repair two times with different options, all default on the first and secure boot disabled the second time. I have four partitions on `/dev/nvme0n1`: an EFI partition, a swap partition, an unused ext4 partition, and my main partition.

I have the [first](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5khbTSRHy4/) and [second](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XjYKkNyz2K/) boot repair outputs. I can't find any solutions online which fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution a few days ago. I doubt very many people will end up in a similar situation, but just in case:

What happened was that I had two bootloaders. I'm not sure *why*, but the default one was what caused that error message to appear.

I fixed it with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228) solution, and everything worked.

The most likely cause of this was installing Ubuntu (as well as a few other distros) multiple times, trying to get things working properly, and unknowingly choosing different partitions for the bootloader.