# Two bootloaders: GRUB and ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

I've tried to install various distros on my laptop quite a few times. As a result, some pretty weird stuff has happened regarding my bootloader. Or rather, my bootloaders. Note that I am not dual booting.

Whenever I turn my computer on and choose `Ubuntu` from the (first) GRUB menu, it says `error symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found`. But if I go to my computer's BIOS/UEFI settings, and exit, it shows two OS bootloaders on the same hard drive (I have one 256GB SSD): `GRUB` and `ubuntu`. When I choose GRUB, it takes me to the first, broken bootloader. But when I choose `ubuntu`, it boots perfectly fine into Ubuntu 20.04.

Some potential causes for this could be:

- Me trying to install 18.04 once with the bootloader in `/dev/nvme0n1`, and another time in `/dev/nvme0n1p1`
- Me trying to fix my 18.04 install by running `grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 --efi-directory=/boot` (I later installed 20.04 and that is what I'm currently using)

I've tried boot repair from a live USB, and it did nothing. My theory is that I have one bootloader on `/dev/nvme0n1`, and one in `/dev/nvme0n1p1` (which is mounted to `/boot/efi`). However, I have no idea how to confirm this or fix anything.

Also, I thought the contents of my `/boot` and `/boot/efi` folders looked a bit strange, so I put the directory tree in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fPWgJvGM) if it helps.

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure boot on? Did you install in UEFI boot mode? It is normal for grub to have both grubx64.efi and shimx64.efi as entries. But a grub entry in UEFI is probably from another install and can be removed with efibootmgr -b. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: @oldfred Worked! Thanks for the help!