# Boot repair unable to solve dual boot problem after Windows Update

Tags: boot, updates, 20.04, windows, bios

I have a Toshiba dynabook Satellite Pro C50-A-1K9 laptop.  It is dual boot system - Ubuntu 20.04LTE and MS Windows10.

After I did the latest Windows update, which included a Toshiba BIOS update to 1.80, the computer will only boot into Windows without showing the usual Ubuntu boot menu.

I ran the boot repair disk from a USB stick, but no change - MS Windows again

Whilst in Windows, as recommended by boot repair, I typed in the Windows command box:-

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

No change - it still boots into MS Windows.

I do have comprehensive backups of my data, but unless there is absolutely no other way, I do not want to start with a fresh install of Ubuntu as there is much software installed and the total size is 1.5Tb

I have been using Ubuntu for several years now and am familiar with the command line.  However, this problem is way out of my league and I would appreciate the assistance of a systems expert!  This page, generated by "boot repair" may be useful-

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wWjQhpn8N9/

It may also be helpful to those who are developing new versions of the boot repair software to hopefully overcome the problems caused by this latest unfortunate update from MS Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try changing the boot priority in the BIOS settings. make the partitions saying Ubuntu as the first one. BIOS update might have set the windows as the first entry.

Comment: try to disable fast startup in Windows 10 or check if Bios has similiar option and then disable...

Comment: UEFI update usually resets many settings to defaults. It probably also turned UEFI Secure Boot on and if Ubuntu was not installed in Secure Boot mode, it would not be seen. You also had Linpus Lite as default in UEFI, best to remove those UEFI entries. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloned-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228  Boot-Repair reinstalled grub and set Ubuntu as first in boot order. Does it now work?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies.

Fast startup in Windows was already disabled.

UEFI secure boot was already OFF

The Toshiba BIOS does not have the facility to directly specify particular partitions for boot, only the disk itself.  Windows used its own settings and therefore booted into Windows by default.

Thank you in particular to the final contributor, "oldfred", for the information on efiboot manager.  I had not come across this before.  I used a combination of rerunning "Boot Repair" with different Advanced Options from before and efiboot manager.  "sudo efibootmgr -v", "sudo efibootmgr man" etc.

My situation is now much better than before in that the computer boots into Ubuntu (great!).  However, when the Windows boot option is selected from the Ubuntu grub menu, it boots into Ubuntu not into Windows.  Quite honestly I may leave it like that with Windows inaccessible as it has caused so much trouble on numerous occasions that Windows is more of a liability than an asset!  I use Ubuntu 98% of the time anyway!  Thanks again.