# GRUB Error During Routine Update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I recently had one of those regular software update messages and went ahead and blindly allowed them. Right before finishing I received the following dialogue message:

Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?

I then clicked "Help" and received the following message:

GRUB failed to install to the following devices:
/dev/nvme0n1p2

Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.

I tried to not continue by clicking Next without checking the box next to the first error message. Ultimately the only way to get out of the dialogue boxes was to check the box and click next.

Did I mess up my GRUB install? I really hate to go through the pain of fixing it if I did and am afraid to reboot my machine now to see because I'm in the middle of an important project. Note that my machine is dual booted with a Windows 10 partition.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is p2 your ESP - efi system partition? Did Windows turn on fast startup or reset UEFI and cause grub not to install? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hello! Yes, p2 is my efi system partition. I ended up risking it and restarting my system to see if I could boot in. Everything is luckily working as normal, though I still don't know what could be causing that error message in the first place. Here is the Boot-Repair summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CspMrqwbyM/

Comment: You have an old Windows BIOS boot in gpt's protective MBR. Just always use UEFI, not legacy/CSM/BIOS settings to boot. And you have two Windows entries, one has partUUID/GUID that does not exist (0000). You can delete that entry in UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloned-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228