# Broken Windows10 dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

community,

I'm struggling now for a huge amount of time on fixing my windows10-ubuntu20.04 dual boot system and I'm now at a point where I need to ask for help.

The story started when I bought a new larger SSD to improve my setup. I cloned the full contents of the old SSD disk onto the new one, using Clonezilla. Everything basically worked out fine until this step. Upon connecting each of the SSDs individually to my mainboard, it was possible to boot 'properly' into the OS of choice.

In order to gain the advantages of the new larger SSD I then had to rearrange the partitions on the drive a little bit, to assign the unallocated space to the desired partitions. This step obviously broke the correct boot behavior and left me with the problem I will now describe as precise as possible.

If I now start my computer the GRUB menu opens as usual providing me the options to start either my windows or ubuntu OS. Booting ubuntu still works without any (recognizable) problems. Nevertheless, upon choosing the windows option, some process is starting, but is either interrupted immediately leading into a complete reboot (bringing me to the GRUB menu again), or occasionally some windows diagnosis and repair 'routine' starts. This ends in a blue screen (not the classical 'bluescreen') where one can choose between some options (Continue, Use a device, Troubleshoot, Turn off your PC).

I assume that shifting the partitions might have caused some trouble with the UEFI setup and I therefore tried to use the boot-repair tool which is recommended in several other posts. I started the recommended option and followed the instructions by executing the shown terminal commands. The resulting message told me that an error occurred during the repair and a log-file was written, which I uploaded here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SNrKFW6FFZ/

In addition I also created the BootInfo summary, which you find here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/trR4j3bW29/

I did not dare yet, to use some of the advanced options of the boot-repair tool. So if anyone can make some sense of these boot-repair outputs and suggest some next steps on a rather intermediate-beginner level, I would be extremely thankful.

Best regards,
Nico

Comment: This is more a *Windows* problem than an Ubuntu one, but ... If your original HDD was GPT formatted and the SSD is MBR formatted (which is what it looks like from the logs you shared), you may need to change the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy. The wrong boot mode will often create issues with operating systems. Depending on how the clone was performed, you may also need to realign the sectors ... but only if you find the SSD to be really, really slow.

Comment: @NicoU Do you have a Win10 installation USB drive/disk, or did you make a [Win10 RE disk/USB drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/) beforehand?

Comment: Boot-Repair says drive is gpt. Does Windows boot directly from UEFI. Grub only boots working Windows or fast start up must be off which Windows regularly turns back on with updates and it cannot need chkdsk which is required after any NTFS partition resize. So either direct boot Windows & run chkdsk and make sure fast start up is off, or use your Windows repair/recovery disk to make repairs. Also houseclean duplicate UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr -b. See `man efibootmgr` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: Thank you @Matigo for pointing out that this is actually a problem concerning windows. This was not completely clear for me beforehand. With this in mind, I managed to fix the problem by simply making a system image from my old SSD and transferring it to the new SSD with the Win10 RE, mentioned by Paul.
This took a while and might not have been the best solution, but it finally resolved my problem. So thanks a lot to you all for sharing your advices! :)