# Windows 10 bootloader missing in GRUB menu over night

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am running a dual boot system on separate SSD.

1.SSD NVMe 256GB Windows 10 came pre installed, upgraded one week ago to PRO.

2.installed my own Samsung 1T 2.5 SATA SSD and installed Ubuntu version 20.04

```
      -partition 1- EFI 650MB us as: EFI
      -partition 2- ROOT 20GB, ext4, mount point: "/"
      -partition 3- SWAP 32GB 
      -partition 4- HOME ~936GB(remainder of space) "/home"
```

target for bootloader was EFI partition.

BIOS version insyde corp. V1.33

-UEFI mode only

-SATA mode AHCI, turned off RST Optane/premium

-safe mode disabled

-fast boot OFF in windows 10 pro power options

-i also have a supervisor password on startup prior to getting into BIOS screen.

flawless install
in UEFI mode boot order was:

1. ubuntu
2. Windows bootloader

during startup, GRUB menu would appear with 10 seconds on clock with the following
1.ubuntu
2.ubuntu advanced settings
3.windows bootloader
4.firmware settings

As of 4/13/2021 3.windows bootloader DISSAPEARED from GRUB menu.
to clarify i wanted the option on startup Through GRUB menu to pick which OS to use. i was happy with things.

now i have a more complex issue. if i want one OS or the Other i MUST change boot order in UEFI during boot. GRUB menu does not show windows anymore.
to further complicate things, i attempt to fix this using a boot-fixer app on ubuntu, and ended up with my bios boot order looking like this:

1.windows bootloader
2.ubuntu
3.LIMPUS LITE
4.ubuntu.

(i have no USB plugged in)

Now I have 2 problems attempting to resolve:

1. get windows bootloader back into GRUB menu
2. Remove redundant, unwanted 3 and 4 in BIOS. They must have gotten there while i was attempting to solve this issue using boot loader/fixer program i pulled from ubuntu library.
   (note. in windows i tried Command prompt admin, all UEFI seem to be active and have a star (*) by them, and the operation to remove them (the unwanted ones) failed.

Any help would be great. the only thing i can think of that "changed," was this seemed to coincide with a windows 10 pro update around this time. however i did not update until after the problem presented itself. The original problem of windows bootloader disappearing from GRUB menu.

thank you.

Comment: Windows updates turns fast start up back on. Check that again. Updates may also update UEFI and reset to defaults, recheck UEFI settings. Ubuntu UEFI entries often have both an entry for "shimx64.efi" and "grubx64.efi" You can remove your old Linpus entry with efibootmgr with most systems. A few sync BCD with UEFI & restore settings and then you can only use UEFI settings and boot settings tab (not boot menu key). See `man efibootmgr` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: so i wiped my SSD. re installed latest ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

so i wiped my SSD. re installed latest ubuntu 20.04 LTS. windows boot-loader re-appeared in GRUB menu. after installing all new Ubuntu updates, restarting, windows boot-loader disappears again. and once entering Ubuntu GUI and terminal, using DISKS, sudo so prober....no longer finds 2nd NVMe SSD with (OEM) pre-installed windows pro. it is not only unmounted, it can not be mounted with any procedures i have found. wiped disk in diskpart windows COMMAND PROMT. AGAIN reinstalled Ubuntu and perfectly mounts my SSD's with windows bootloader INCLUDED in GRUB menu as i wanted. so until i find a solution, i will not be updating or installing Ubuntu upgrades. i just want a bios free, smooth transition between OS's (on different drives) using the pretty GRUB menu. not sure what else to do. ive tried multiple re-installs and countless procedures on the forums with no luck. something in the newest upgrade is causing this.