# The best way to fix the GRUB EFI boot loader folder to the right FAT32 boot partition in Multi SSD/NVMe OSes installed?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

As the picture below, in the past I have installed few times the Ubuntu for differetn testing. But in the last Ubuntu OS installation on my new SSD, I devided the partition for my needs and created the FAT32 Boot Partition to save the Grub Boot. Because I have 4 SSD/Nvme with different OSes installed and separated from each other (Windows 10 Home, Windows 10 Pro , Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu 21.04) , last time I'm sure 100% that I have choosen the right driver to install the GRUB EFI bootloader but could be that something happen on my old previous installations and happen that the OS it's installed in `/sda` partition but the Grub it's installed into the `/nvme0n1p2`.

If I copy the EFI folder from `/nvme0n1p2` and paste it into the right SSD FAT32 Partition `/sda` and change the boot UUID into a file system (that now I don't remember the name), I will solve like that? or there is some other way?

The system working well, it's just to take out the extra voice on BIOS Drive Selection once I need to choose which drivers with the OS need to be start because now I have two Ubuntu selection under two SSD drivers......

GRUB wrong EFI path:
[image]

[image]

GRUB boot loader EFI where shoud be:

[image]

[image]

I hope it's understandable because some words are in my language......

Comment: UEFI entry boots using GUID/partUUID of ESP.  `sudo efibootmgr -v` shows guid/partUUID. Ubuntu's ubiquity only installs grub to first ESP. Multiple workarounds during install or just totally re-install grub in UEFI mode afterwards, grub works to install to any ESP. Change flags before install.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 Please add to this: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: @oldfred thanks to reply, I made your suggestions with `sudo efibootmgr -v` and for strange on the list appear the file into the folder but in the Disk manager I cannot see as you can see above. I attach below the pic of the result....

Comment: Use this to see partUUID/GUID of current partitions: `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`  Then see `man efibootmgr` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228  UEFI remembers old entries. You have to manually delete any obsolete ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because so far no guide solutionts come in , so, I have solved everything by my self. If you will face the same situation or similiar like mine, with no GRUB installed in the right SSD/HDD where is located the UBUNTU/Linux OS - but you have created the EFI partition for it - and you have found some Extra BOOT/ GRUB Linux voice in the BIOS/ Start Up Section in wrong SSD/HDD because you have installed Multi OSes into your PC…. So, below are the simplest and clear SOLUTIONS to solved it without to going mad or reinstall everything:

1. Get and install **Boot-Repair** (from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair ) in your Linux as below:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

2. Once installed the App, open it and press Advanced Options (on Down Left).
3. Follow the Pics below (it’s in my language, but it’s understandable which Option you have to select). So,  go on Second Flag - Page GRUB Location - and from the sub 3 voices on the first one go to choose your Ubuntu OS Location from the list and **Uncheck the second Voice** and **Check the Third Voice** so on the list should appear the EFI FAT32 Partition empty where should be the GRUB, in my case the SSD it’s `sda`, so the OS in `sda2` and the GRUB need to be installed into `sda1` (all the rest listed Partitions, are just the external Windows FAT32 Partitions because you have the Multiboot). After that, jump to the Fift Flag - Other Options – and **Uncheck the first Voice**. Then, press **Apply**.

[image]

4. Once done it, reboot your system and into your Bios should appear the new Voice under start up devices sections with the right SSD/HDD device. Add as the first priority to understand if it’s working and from the BIOS disable the rest of the extra wrong SSD UBUNTU voices.
5. Reboot and you should be able to run UBUNTU without Problems (if not don’t continue with what I’m writing, and check well if you did everything correctly).
6. Now, let’s delete the other annoying UBUNTU/GRUB voices, you have to find the FAT32 Windows OS in external SSD/HDD, and open it by UBUNTU.
7. Once find it, open the FAT32 Partition and go into `EFI` folder and you should find 3 folders:

- Boot
- Microsoft
- ubuntu

8. Delete the `ubuntu` folder.
9. Don’t touch the `Microsoft` folder and go directly into the `Boot` folder,  into the `Boot` folder you should find the following **.efi** Voices (some times all of of them sometimes less):

- bkpbootx64.efi
- bootx64.efi
- fbx64.efi
- grubx64.efi
- mmx64.efi

So, from these 5 **.efi** voices, **keep only bootx64.efi** and all the rest you can delete. PLEASE, be carefully on that because it’s vital for your Windows OS Partition to start up the OS. To be more safe on it, before any action, you can copy all these EFI folders in your Ubuntu Desktop and delete what I said. And restart or start all the Multiboot (especially Windows side ) to understand that you made everything correctly. Once all the system start up well, you can Delete completely your copy files/folder from your Ubuntu Desktop.

And all the extra BIOS voices will dessapear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @oldfred, finally it seems that this problem related to the Multiboot it has some sense now (after using this command `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` ).
Last time the **GRUB Boot Loader** it installed in wrong Partitions even if I gave - for sure - the right flag and Partition to install it (next time better to keep just one alone SSD driver connected during the Linux installation).
So it seems that GUI Disk Manager was right that into the FAT32 EFI Partition it's empty, because GRUB Boot Loader it's installed into two partition as I demostrate into the PIC below and for some reason it keeps the same UUID for both `/nvme0n1p2` and `/nvme1n1p2`, maybe it's the reson why before yesterday I have tried to take out the UBUNTU GRUB folder from one of the NVME wrong Partition and the OS still Starts, because there is another GRUB where the system it boot from the Second Windows NVME if cannot find from the first.
Now, because the Operation related to the GRUB it's delicate, otherwise I risk to don't let the OS to boot anymore; I need someone more expert to Guide me step by step on it.

[image]

I believe that the first step, it's to install GRUB in the right SSD Partition/ Position and it's the `/sda1` partition and then test if will boot it, and then once sure everything it's fine on it, to delete the two WRONG GRUB Boot Loader into `/nvme0n1p2` and `/nvme1n1p2`. I have read the internet addresses forwarded, but are fragmented information that I need to collect and I'm not sure if I still to mistake on it. So, please, I need someone that Guide me on my specific situation.

Thanks a lot Cris