# rEFInd has multiple `grubx64.efi` entries

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, refind

I have installed rEFInd to use on my desktop, which I am dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 10. In the past, I have simply ran `refind-install` and `refind-mkdefault`, and it has worked perfectly.

However, I have recently re-installed and there are now 2 entries for `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` detected by rEFInd. So, when it shows the menu there are 2 identical Ubuntu entries. But, the problem is that one of them drops me to a grub prompt and the other actually boots ubuntu.

They are identical, even to rEFInd, because rEFInd is supposed to boot the last-booted OS unless you change at startup, but it mixes them up (i.e. if I reboot after selecting the real Ubuntu option, it will automatically boot to the grub shell instead)

Has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: rEFInd detected EFI entries there were already there.

Comment: UEFI remembers old entries. What does `sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` Show? Compare GUID in efibootmgr to partUUID (GUID) in lsblk. Some may be from old partition that does not exist? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloned-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 or `man efibootmgr`