# Unable to repair grub on dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

Something went wrong with my dual boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10. I have windows in installed on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD. It started to give me a black screen on boot with no ubuntu logo/splash screen and no lcd light. I tried all possible ways to fix it and it wont work.
I tried to do a grub repair using a live boot usb disk.
Now I end up with a broken boot with basic grub command line. The boot repair tool doesn't fix this. Can someone please help me with the issue.
Attaching link to the file generated by boot repair tool.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ngVZgRvNft/

Laptop Lenovo Legion Y540

Comment: It was or is showing Linpus Lite as default boot in UEFI. But reinstall of grub should have made Ubuntu's grub as first in UEFI. You can remove old UEFI entries with efibootmgr, see `man efibootmgr` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloned-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 Normally efibootmgr will be used by grub to reset boot order. If not, go into UEFI settings and change boot order there.

Comment: The default boot Linpus Lite showing is for the external USB (Live Boot Disk).

Comment: No the default Linpus Lite entry is using the GUID of your internal drive's ESP. So if you have removed flash drive, it will try to boot a grub that is not there. To see UEFI entries which use GUID/partUUID: `sudo efibootmgr -v` and to see partUUID of your partitions: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,model,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,partuuid` Both shown in Boot-Repair's Summary Report.  External drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and name or label of flash drive, not of a distribution. Full install to external may put entry in internal ESP.

Comment: I tried deleting the entries using efibootmgr. The machine will still boot me to basic command line grub. I tried running the repair tool again. It still doesn't work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/42gPs8sf2j/

Comment: Am not sure I have seen a report with so many new issues. It looks like you uninstalled the desktop and have corruption in Windows or Windows fast start up locking ESP. You now only have Linpus lite, no Ubuntu UEFI entry? Grub could not reinstall. And then it did some sort of dump of log files with other errors. May be best now to just reinstall & restore from your backups as not much is working.

Comment: Thank you so much Oldfred. Got to reinstall the system now.

Comment: Typically any system can be fixed with enough effort. But with good backups, a reinstall can often be quicker & easier. I do a lot of test installs and now have scripted 80% of configuration. I can install to pre-partitioned SSD from RAM (toram boot parameter) in about 10min. Script is quick. Download of list of additionsal apps is then slowest part of reinstall, depending on Internet speed. Or in about an hour I have full working install. But we do spend days trying to help a user fix broken system, if desired.