# How to remove external disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I first installed Ubuntu on an external drive to get familiar with it before moving it to the internal drive.  So far so good but now that I moved Ubuntu on the internal drive, I cannot remove the external drive.  Sounds like the EFI of the external drive is the one that is used instead of the one from the internal drive.

I tried to use boot-repair but boot-repair thinks I dont have an EFI partition on the internal drive.  It is asking me to create one with the ESP and BOOT flag on.  It is already there.

On the internal drive, I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu.  They both runs properly and are accessed by GRUB.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it was me I would re install without the external drive attached.

Comment: reinstall Ubuntu?  And then what?  copy back my disk image over this new installation?

Comment: If the system works without the external disk connected.
Disconnect the external hard drive.
Reinstall Grub on Ubuntu, selecting the internal disk as the installation site.

Comment: Check your fstab? It may have wrong UUID for ESP? Or check UEFI and partUUID of UEFI boot entry. `cat /etc/fstab` & `sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -f -o +PARTUUID` UEFI uses GUID aka partuuid

Comment: Thanks kyodake.  But I did reinstalled Grub several time already.

Comment: @oldfred that sounds like a good idea.  But I might not know enough to handle this completly by myself.   I see that in fstab, there are several lines now with the UUID (some very long numbers, others only 2 groups of 4 digits)(this is since I ran boot-repair several times).  Also, efibootmgr shows several entries that are no longer use.

Comment: Post link to summary report as it runs all those commands as part of report. Just post link to pastebin site it gives.You can remove obsolete UEFI entries with efibootmgr. see `man efibootmgr` and -b XXXX -B parameters. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: I think this is what you requested:https://pastebin.com/acL2MzVQ

Comment: The UUID in the fstab was related to the external drive. I replaced it with the one from the internal drive. It made no difference.  It's almost like if that file was not looked

Answer (score 0):

For information only... I finally ended up by re-installing Ubuntu on the local drive, while the external drive was unpluged.  Now it is working.

I wish I could boot-repaired it.  I started re-installing every software from scratch.  At least now, it is working like a charm!

Comment: The question should probably be closed since reinstalling Ubuntu is generally not a helpful answer.  Glad to hear that the problem is resolved though.

Comment: You’re completely right Nmath.  By « closing it » you mean delete?  I can delete it but i get a message that i should not do that...   i wish i had find better solution but...