# Dual boot recognizes both as ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I used my PC which has SSD with windows installed. I unplugged my laptop HDD and connected it to PC and it was working fine.

Then I unplugged laptop hdd from PC and installed ubuntu on PC, works fine.

Now when I connect HDD(windows) to PC and in BIOS I select to boot from that HDD it boots in Ubuntu...

Also I tried via grub menu, it only shows ubuntu

Comment: If you unplug system with UEFI boot, it forgets the UEFI boot entry. And may keep old entries which then you should houseclean. To repair Windows use a Windows repair flash drive or full installer with repair console. To remove Ubuntu UEFI entry use efibootmgr from Ubuntu live installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: You can use 'super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s10.iso' or an 'Ikki-boot.iso' to boot from. ( put it on a usb-stick). If you boot form there 'super_rub2_disk' will recognize all your bootable systems. Boot to the system you want and do the repair(s) needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.

I fixed the issue by simply updating my kernel version