# Ubuntu installed in dual boot does not boot after repartitioning and reinstallation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had to re-install my Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with my Windows 10 PC which had been working fine. I re-installed after repartitioning to give more space to Linux.

I can no longer access the Ubuntu OS even though I can see it with
GParted. sda3 is Windows OS and sda5 is Ubuntu OS.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Running boot repair I have the following logs:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8xXRGy6sTd/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Rn3sprZCgG/

However, when I restart the PC, Windows is loaded straight away and the GRUB menu is not shown.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {bacce4a7-f7ac-11ea-a1f9-998806de144f}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         No

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {bacce4a9-f7ac-11ea-a1f9-998806de144f}
displaymessageoverride  CommandPrompt
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {bacce4a7-f7ac-11ea-a1f9-998806de144f}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Going through the UEFI Firmware Settings, Ubuntu is not an option in the boot priority order, only Windows.

I have tried setting the bootmgr path to `\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi` however the PC just resets itself continually and won't even start Windows.

I just wondered what I can do to restore the GRUB menu or what further information is required.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? It says grub was correctly installed & UEFI is showing ubuntu entry as first in boot order? You also have a lot of duplicate UEFI boot entries. Best to remove those. Use efibootmgr & -b parameter as shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 Unknown like you have is often from Acer which requires you to set "trust" and rename the unknown entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)