# Grub Command line shows up before menu

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, 22.04

I'm stuck with grub at command line on boot.

I can boot into Windows 11 or Ubuntu 22.04 by typing `exit` every time to load the grub menu, however, I would like to fix this.

Perhaps worth noting I have 3 x 1 TB SATA SSDs in my system and am happy to share any required results.

**I have tried the following fix on a Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB (*didn't
change anything though*):**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Lastly, while going through some solutions I thought it might be worth it to give you the output from running an `ls` on the command line that pops up on boot.

The output of running an `ls` is as below:

`(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt5) (hd2,gpt4) (hd2,gpt3) (hd2,gpt2) (hd2,gpt1)`

Here's the [report summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpZVNZtpxh/) from boot-repair

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post link that Boot-Repair gives when you run its Summary Report. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Are all installs UEFI and is system's default boot mode then UEFI?

Comment: @oldfred apologies for the late reply. 
Here's the paste: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpZVNZtpxh/

Comment: Only use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose and install and a drive. You have two ESP which is ok since on different drives. But one Windows entry 0000 boots grub and should be deleted, and Ubuntu entry 0004 uses ESP in sdc2. Ubuntu 0002 uses ESP in sdb2. Grub.cfg in sdc2 does not have correct UUID for full grub.cfg. Remove 0000 & 0004. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloned-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 Not sure if booting correct ubuntu entry, if you  would still have any issues or not.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused about this - the action I have to take is to remove 0000 and 0004?

Comment: And then see if the remaining entries work. Or then a total reinstall of grub.