# Why does my dualboot only detect ubuntu and not win10?

Tags: boot, windows, boot-partition

I have win10 and ubuntu installed on a single ssd, both OS on a separate particion. My bootloader does not give me an option to choose windows and boots ubuntu automatically.

This is my disk diagnosis: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fDqy82dYR5/

Comment: you have to run `sudo update-grub` inside Ubuntu so that it will recognize the installed Windows, especially if you installed Windows afterwards. You may also have to add `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` in `/etc/default/grub`, and run `sudo update-grub` again.

Comment: Drive is MBR(msdos), so Windows is in BIOS boot mode. Even though a grub is in MBR, the live installer was booted in UEFI mode, and grub was reinstalled in UEFI mode as the mount of ESP is in fstab (line 219). Not sure if grub in MBR still works or not, if you boot Ubuntu in BIOS mode. You also have many duplicate UEFI entries and need to delete those. Years ago systems were totally bricked with too many entries, so best to houseclean duplicates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228