# Dual Boot ubuntu 22.04 with bootable sandisk drive. Grub does not display boot options

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-legacy

Installed ubuntu 22.04 via sandisk USB, duel boot with windows 10 on a Dell machine. When I turn on the laptop GNU GRUB (version 2.06) is displayed with the grub> prompt. I can not selected Windows or ubuntu. I install the usb sandisk and change the bios to UEFI: SanDisk and the machine bring up ubuntu from the USB drive. Note, Windows is also UEFI BOOT.

I added a swap, root and home partitions. Tried to install ubuntu got an UEFI error. Added an UEFI partition. Now the GNU GRUB screen is displayed.

????
Dan

...
The UEFI error occurred at the initial startup after installation. Reference paste.unbuntu.com/p/9K8vhG3XCF

Comment: In which step, the installer throw an UEFI error? Partitioning or installing?

Comment: You should only have one ESP per device/drive. If ESP that Windows is using is not correctly seen make sure Windows fast start up is off. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred - Ran Boot-Repair, Ref. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bs4CbFB5BN   please review and comment before I initiate repair.

Comment: You say Windows is UEFI, but only a BIOS mode Vista is shown? And then drive is MBR, not preferred gpt. Windows in UEFI mode, has to be gpt. You cannot mix BIOS & UEFI on same drive as Windows has to have boot flag on its bootable partition, and UEFI has to have esp,boot flags on the ESP. With UEFI hardware better to use UEFI with gpt, but since system is MBR, you can reinstall the BIOS version of grub which it looks like Boot-Repair has auto selected.  Also remove the many duplicate UEFI entries with efibootmgr. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

Comment: @oldfred - It appears I followed your directions as it's working. When I start the computer, I still get “Invalid partition table!” but when I hit enter the grub menu is displayed.
After all of this, if I decide to download Ubuntu as a single boot (remove windows) will that remove the Dell partition (sda1) as well? I appreciate you helping me out on this oldfred, I could not have done it without your input.

Comment: @oldfred - ref. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ysYzvtmz9w

Comment: I converted to UEFI boot with my new z97/Haswell build in 2014. I had previously started to convert drives to gpt with BIOS boot, then started to add an ESP for future use to all new/repartitioned drives. But conversion from MBR to gpt typically erases entire drive, so good backups are required. Ubuntu will use MBR(msdos) with UEFI, but that is not really recommended. If also thinking of a new drive, a SSD can really improve boot & loading times.