# 2 EFI partitions on single disk, which one to delete?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had windows 10 on my drive after I got preinstalled ubunutu removed. Then I installed, Kubuntu and then while installing Fedora 36, I added another EFI file. I want to delete my windows partion.

Now, I've 2 EFI partitions on my drive. As mentioned above, one is pre Linux distros (KU22 & F36) installation and second one is that I added alongwith Fedora. Which one should I delete? Should I also delete recovery and Microsoft reserved partion along with efi and other ntfs (windows) partition?

This is the exact picture of my partition manager.

1. NTFS          Recovery Basic data partition
2. Fat32 /boot/EFI ESP
3. Unknown       Microsoft reserved partition
4. NTFS          Basic data partition
5. NTFS          Basic data partition
6. Unknown (Unallocated)
7. NTFS
8. Ext4 /
9. Ext4 /home
10. Fat32.       ESP
11. Ext4 /
12. Ext4 /home

```
(1 2 3 4 5 7) Windows
(8 9) Ubuntu
(10 11 12) Fedora
```

If I delete (123457) or (134579), will I able to boot both Ubuntu & Fedora from (9) or (1) only?

Comment: This question seems to be about 2 EFI System Partitions (ESP) rather than 2 EFI "files". Usually 1 physical SSD/HDD should have 1 ESP. It is not clear if you have 1 or 2 physical drives. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1419292/edit) and clarify.

Comment: Better to show partitions `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` The partUUID/GUID is use by UEFI to know which ESP to use. So compare partUUID with `sudo efibootmgr -v` to know which systems is using which ESP. You probably have to update fstab first &  totally reinstall grub to one ESP you save & houseclean old entries in UEFI to old ESP.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you please guide step-by-step?

Comment: Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and copy and paste all this `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` in a single line and then hit Enter. Then copy the output (you can use the mouse and Right click) and paste it directly in your question. Finally format the pasted text as `code` by using the {_} icon above the Edit Question window. Repeat the same copy and past the output process for the command `sudo efibootmgr -v`.