# Ubuntu line in boot order of devices

Tags: usb, boot-order

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a USB stick.
So now I can boot from the USB stick and install Ubuntu or try it out.

I want to install it on another USB stick to have a portable Linux I can run everywhere.
With try Ubuntu I always have to do too many changes after starting it.
After installation on the other USB stick I can boot  but Ubuntu changed the boot order, by default my laptop will now boot from the USB stick.

If I choose Ubuntu in the boot menu Ubuntu starts fine.
If I select Windows windows fails and goes into startup recovery.

If I change the boot order and set windows bootloader on top, windows boots fine
If I boot and hit F12 to change the boot order temporarily and then choose my USB device
the boot of Ubuntu fails and I end up in PC recovery.
If I select Ubuntu int the menu of boot devices, Ubuntu boots fine.

So on my laptop I know what to do to boot Ubuntu or Windows.
But I like to use that stick to boot on another laptop and I will not have Ubuntu in the list of bootable devices but I will see the USB stick.

Did the installation did write something on my disk in the laptop, I do not know.
How to enable the boot from USB to boot Ubuntu.
How to delete the Ubuntu device from the list of bootable devices?

My laptop is a Lenovo X1 Extreme 2nd gen with windows 11.

Comment: The Ubiquity installer has an old unfixed bug. Also work arounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 You need to manually partition and have an ESP - efi system partition on any external drive. Remove UEFI entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

Comment: Well this explanation is very very good.It really helped me to boot from a standalone ubuntu USB stick. Works fine on all systems but I do have a side effect on my Lenovo.
Every time I boot from the ubuntu stick it will add an ubuntu boot option in the list of possible boot drives, if I delete this option it will come back the next time I boot from the stick.
I tried on two other systems and I have never seen the ubuntu boot option appearing.

Comment: I have seen others with many UEFI entries and have wondered where they came from. External drive should not automatically add new entry to UEFI. External UEFI boot drives boot from UEFI:XXXX entry where XXX is drive name or label. My systems often says PMAP. And that UEFI entry is always /EFi/Boot/bootx64.efi. The bootx64.efi may be a copy of grub/shim or a Windows  installer's file, or any other system boot file like rEFInd. UEFI often automatically adds a Windows boot entry if new /EFI/Microsoft folder found, but almost none add an Ubuntu entry for /EFI/ubuntu folder.