# mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty) - not booting anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

My Ubuntu 22.04 wont boot anymore, as it get's stuck after `[ OK ] Started Tool to automatically collect and sbumit kernel crash signatures.`

Before that, it just shows the message in the title and afterwards it stays black with a blinking underscore.

To be honest, I had problems with the booting process from the beginning, having a dual boot - with separate drives though.

One possible issue could be, that I had to delete the syslog file, after a VLC error filled up my whole 2 TB SSD.

I tried already:

- obviously `update && upgrade`
- fixing the fstab file: changed the `errors=remount-ro` to `rw,user,exec`
- boot to live environment and install `Boot Repair`, used *"Recommended repair"*
- copy the received error message as follows:

boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20220909_1415]

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme1n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p2
OS#2:   Windows 7 on nvme1n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Ti] AlderLake-S GT1 EFI VGA from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F7(5.24) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0003,0004,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,0534a66d-f54a-459b-a55f-ff9348bca723,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001  Fedora    HD(1,GPT,95613559-aa89-4d11-ab7a-b9c9a455c51a,0x800,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\FEDORA\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,70c9652f-52e5-4481-a1d9-241fcaff08d8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,0534a66d-f54a-459b-a55f-ff9348bca723,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(9,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xf51564,0x800,0x3a97800)..BO

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
8a9ec3de9d79349c2e34b580fe655ee5   nvme1n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme1n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   nvme1n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
8a9ec3de9d79349c2e34b580fe655ee5   nvme1n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
59f8328db22467a564e7173962244df0   nvme1n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme1n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme1n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme1n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme1n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme1n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme1n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme1n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1
nvme1n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1
nvme1n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: E41874A8-EEF2-4D46-A1DB-1CE0198386E1
            Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem
Disk nvme1n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0552076F-03DA-4096-940B-6302D8A2D259
               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
nvme1n1p2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme1n1p3     239616 1952347759 1952108144 930.8G Microsoft basic data
nvme1n1p4 1952348160 1953519615    1171456   572M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00f51564
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 61439999 61437952 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:2000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:2000GB:2000GB:ext4::;
nvme1n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:1000GB:999GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:1000GB:1000GB:600MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     7830-B809                            00f51564-01                          UBUNTU 22_0 
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     8854-A9E6                            70c9652f-52e5-4481-a1d9-241fcaff08d8             EFI System Partition
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3 f9f6b553-fc0a-44be-aafa-7b0747be1103             
nvme1n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat     9622-D13A                            0534a66d-f54a-459b-a55f-ff9348bca723             EFI system partition
├─nvme1n1p2                                               7f7d1f70-1654-4b3a-a302-1f06a6ea7155             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme1n1p3 ntfs     783623A23623607C                     98f7b52f-72f7-4ac9-8a84-3abea139290f             Basic data partition
└─nvme1n1p4 ntfs     2866CA6766CA357A                     cf5216d0-2466-4b44-8e2b-5f44ec4c7963             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1         504.8M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2           1.1T  35% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme1n1p1          63.7M  34% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p1
/dev/nvme1n1p3         581.9G  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p3
/dev/nvme1n1p4          89.6M  84% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p4
/dev/sda1               25.8G  12% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p2         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme1n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme1n1p3         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme1n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-47-generic   529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-46-generic   529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-41-generic   529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme1n1p1)   osprober-efi-9622-D13A
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=529bd243-5f5f-452f-9062-1a470e00c4a3 /               ext4    rw,user,exec 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=8854-A9E6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=783623A23623607C /mnt/783623A23623607C auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 484.634853363 = 520.372711424  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
1185.133785248 = 1272.527712256 boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  13.550361633 = 14.549590016   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic                 2
  73.019527435 = 78.404120576   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic                 1
1185.133785248 = 1272.527712256 boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-47-generic                 2
  73.019527435 = 78.404120576   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  77.317760468 = 83.019313152   boot/initrd.img                                1
  86.816905975 = 93.218942976   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic              1
   3.192726135 = 3.428163584    boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic              1
  77.317760468 = 83.019313152   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic              1
   3.192726135 = 3.428163584    boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15 21:50 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15 21:50 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15 21:50 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15 21:50 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15 21:50 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15 21:50 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15 21:50 41_custom

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd =========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: While there is a bug on mtd device issue, just about everyone says it does not stop boot. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622  Your 0002 ubuntu UEFI entry looks correct. But not 0003 & old Fedora entry. You can use efibootmgr to remove old entries in ESP. `man efibootmgr` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options. Can you boot recovery mode, or second line in grub menu? If you get grub menu, then not boot issue, but loading some driver after grub.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I removed the old entries, still no luck. I do get to the grub menu, though recently no recovery option anymore.
As I mentioned, I'm not sure whether the issue arises due to the mtd-device-issue. Just know that it won't boot anymore and I would really like to avoid making a clean reinstall again.
Again, it might be correlated to my VLC installation... Any help there would be much appreciated

Comment: Run away log files indicate some problem that must be fixed. Do this show anything? `Review log files
sudo grep -Ei 'warn|error' /var/log/*g` I get multiple errors/warnings, but none are critical, some are just comments during boot that mention error in description.