# Cannot boot Linux with Windows (nothing works)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I konw I know. Probably the 1000th post about this but I really feel like I have tried everything.

Grub2Win, BootRepair. Manually reinstalling grub from live usb stick.. Nothing.

So A while ago I had a working dual boot with Windows 10 and Fedora. I wanted to swap to Ubuntu and dont really remember how I did it. Installed ubuntu and boom. no more fedora, no more ubuntu, just windows.

I tried grub2win added an entry to the drive I installed ubuntu on, but I could never get grub2win to boot.

In windows I deleted all the

If I go into the boot manager I see:

1. fedoragrubx64
2. gnugrubkernel64
3. fedora
4. Windows Boot Manager

which is infuriating and disappointing since I deleted all fedora related EFI stuff using `bcdedit /enum firmware` and `bcdedit /delete`.

I tried [this questions marked answer step by step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

I tried boot-repair-disk. with the recommended settings.
Created a pastebin with the output
https://pastebin.com/hH5ae1Zi
(which looks like a mess tbh).

I imagine I should clean this efi drive but I dont know how to without getting my windows nuked as well..

Also sorry if this is not the correct forum point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this an Acer? What model? You show unknown device in UEFI boot entries. See line 91 and many other duplicates. With Acer you have to set "trust" in UEFI settings. Most need UEFI Secure boot on, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to open more settings. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290594 Remove duplicates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Boot Repair output indicates EFI-mode installs of both Windows and Ubuntu, although there are hints that `/dev/sda` may have been used for a BIOS-mode install of Windows in the past, and a BIOS-mode Linux distribution may have existed on `/dev/sdb` in the past. I believe that these are issues of archaeology, though, not recent events.

Given that Boot Repair hasn't worked for you, my suggestion is this:

1. Download the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and write it to a USB flash drive. (You'll need to unpack the `.zip` file and follow the instructions in the `README-flashdrive.txt` file it contains.) You could use the CD-R version instead, if your computer has an optical drive.
2. Plug in the USB flash drive, reboot the computer, and use the computer's own boot manager to boot the USB flash drive. (Details vary from one machine to another, but if you booted an Ubuntu installer, you presumably know how to do this.) The result should be the rEFInd menu appearing.
3. In rEFInd, try booting both Windows and Ubuntu. Both *should* work, but it's conceivable you'll have problems to overcome. Note that the Ubuntu boot is likely to display a lot of text rather than a nice graphical splash screen, but don't worry about that right now.
4. Once you can boot both Windows and Ubuntu, you can then try either of two things:

   - Open a Terminal window in Ubuntu and type `sudo grub-install` to try to get GRUB working from the actual Ubuntu installation. This has a better chance of working than Boot Repair from an emergency medium.
   - Install rEFInd to your hard disk. You can do this from the rEFInd menu (there's a second-row option to install from the USB drive to the hard disk); or in an Ubuntu Terminal window by typing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind` followed by `sudo apt install refind`. (You can actually omit the first command, but that will install an older version of rEFInd, so I recommend using the PPA.)

***In theory,*** this procedure should get you up and running. In practice, there could be something wrong with your installation that's not obvious to me from my examination of your Boot Repair output, or you could hit some quirky stumbling block. If you get to the final step and try to install GRUB but that doesn't work, you can try to install rEFInd afterwards, or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank You!!! This software is legendary. I ended up installing it from usb drive since sudo grub-install from ubuntu did not work. Although it shown something pretty weird. At the "main menu" it displayed a windows boot, a grub boot, an ubuntu boot (from efi I guess) and another ubuntu boot from installation. but when I went into efi editor (efi boot order editor) it only showed what I posted initially as boot options: 2 fedora and a grub boot options.

Comment: EFI maintains its own list of boot options that are stored in NVRAM. Those are shown in the computer's own boot menu when you hit F11 or F12 or whatever your computer uses for this purpose. rEFInd, though, actively scans all the partitions it can read looking for boot options. Thus, rEFInd can show a very different set of options than what the EFI's boot menu shows. The main rEFInd screen includes a tool to adjust the EFI's NVRAM-based boot options, the intent being to provide a tool to help manage the computer's own boot order if it gets messed up. Anyhow, I'm glad rEFInd worked for you!