# UBUNTU take over?

Tags: ssd

NOOB here with Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu on a windows PC. Somehow i missed the step where I was supposed to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows. So I have an Ubuntu only PC. I want to get rid of Ubuntu, so I removed and re-formatted my SSD drive on a laptop. When I go to start up the PC I'm writing with now, it keeps bringing up Ubuntu. Mind you, I supposedly reformatted the ssd in my pc. Can someone help me wipe out Ubuntu on this PC? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you totally reformatted SSD, then you deleted the ESP with Ubuntu boot files. But UEFI may still have an entry. Did you look in UEFI settings & boot tab (not UEFI one time boot menu)? You should be able to remove entry there. If not you can use Ubuntu live installer & efibootmgr. see `man efibootmgr` and -b command.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228