Windows files available in ubuntu, booting and bios problem
I wanted to have two systems installed on ososbian SSD drives. I installed Ubuntu twice. The first time, I divided the second SSD into partitions and unnecessarily initialized them in Windows. Because of this, after the first Ubuntu installation, in the "boot option" in bios, the Ubuntu boot option had the first SSD (SX8200PNP) added, so I deleted this partition from windows. I then reinstalled Ubuntu, creating a partition for it in the installation editor. As a result, in the "boot option" Ubuntu boot option had a good disk (Samsung SSD 970) added.
Unfortunately the BIOS still has the old option to boot Ubuntu from the SX8200PNP drive. How to remove it? In addition, in Ubuntu I have access to files and folders that are on the SX8200PNP drive in Windows. Does this mean that I have not separated the two systems 100% from each other? In the picture, I added the result of sudo fdisk -l and the folders that are in Windows, which are visible from Ubuntu.
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat   FAT32       28FD-9DDA                                           
├─nvme0n1p2
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p3
│    ntfs               D85A0C655A0C432C                      112,4G    60% /media/patryk/D85A0C655A0C432C
├─nvme0n1p4
│    ntfs         Nowy  B6CA94D1CA948F6D                       38,1G    80% /media/patryk/Nowy1
└─nvme0n1p5
     ntfs               7C38C98838C9423E                                    
nvme1n1
│                                                                           
├─nvme1n1p1
│                                                                           
├─nvme1n1p2
│    ntfs         Nowy  8E7AD7E47AD7C75D                      579,9G     0% /media/patryk/Nowy
├─nvme1n1p3
│    vfat   FAT32       7A8D-4979                             505,9M     1% /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p4
     ext4   1.0         8b6cf1bc-df1d-4ac5-a597-bb56219d203c  304,6G     2% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                            /




Fdisk always includes the loops (snaps), better to use lsblk -e 7 -f and post as code, not screenshot. But this will show UEFI boot entries: sudo efibootmgr -v And you can tell if different ESP - efi system partitions are used, by comparing partUUID/guid in efibootmgr.  lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid to include partuuid. And you can use efibootmgr with its -b command to remove UEFI entries. man efibootmgr https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options

I added the result of the command lsblk -e 7 -f
