Ubuntu: cannot boot with USB
I had Ubuntu installed on a separate disk from my Windows. The disk had both the Ubuntu and the grub. I deleted it directly from the Windows disk manager because I wanted to re-install Ubuntu. But when I put back the booted usb with Ubuntu 24.04 (I tried with Rufus, etcher, etc) I jumped the grub rescue. I saw in a video that deleting the Ubuntu folder /EFI in the /System32 no longer came out. I did and now I do not get the grub. To start the PC with the bootable USB, I have searched a thousand of sites and I have not found one solution. The USB works OK because I downloaded a Windows ISO and if I took it to boot properly.

You have to boot the USB flash drive in UEFI mode from UEFI one time boot menu. The "ubuntu" entry in UEFI is trying to boot into the ESP partition you deleted. You can remove the old entry with efibootmgr. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 An UEFI update may have reset it to defaults. And then you may have to turn allow USB boot or similar setting in UEFI settings.

Some machine's UEFI settings have a second layer for determining the boot order.  This second layer may be called "UEFI hard disk order", but includes the USB hdd too.  This ordering may be what is shown in the UEFI boot menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select the boot device/os).
