Manual partitioning for a dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 will not proceed
When going through the Ubuntu 24.04 installer (the new one I believe) attempting to dual boot with windows 11 (UEFI), the installer does not automatically recognize the windows boot loader, and only prompts me to either wipe a drive entirely or manually partition them. When manually partitioning, I am able to create the partitions I want (boot, swap, home, etc) but the option to proceed with the install is greyed out regardless of what partitions I create. The device for boot loader installation drop down also will not let me select either my SSD or HDD. I would like to have some space allocated to each OS on each drive if possible.
I previously installed Arch, which worked fine, but the OS is still detected by my BIOS. It fails to boot as I have deleted the associated partitions, but that could be causing issues with the detection of windows? I have uninstalled the boot loader to the best of my ability.

Please clarify more, you deleted grub? how you uninstalled the boot loader? or you mean arch? you mean you cannot select SSD as the install partition ? you sure you wrote "/" as the mountpoint ?

@haytham-med I deleted everything that i knew wasn't associated with windows from my first partition, which included grub. The drop down for "device for boot loader installation" shows the HDD SSD and USB drive, but all of them are grey and it won't let me select them. I did use / as the mount point for my largest partition on the ssd.

How about output of "lsblk" command ? and a screenshot of gparted partitioning scheme that you are trying to create... Can you still boot into windows? i doubt that grub can be removed this way, please re-install grub using boot-repair or something...

lsblk output partitions I can still boot into windows just fine, essentially the same as before the arch install, the grub loader is not accessible through any of the boot options my BIOS shows. I uninstalled it that way because I had already removed arch, and I found another question with that as a solution.

Can you put link to the solution here?

Sometimes the button appears in gray because you didn't specified where to mount /boot/efi partition. You should mount it on the ESP/EFI System Partition Win 11 installer created(Typically is the first partition, has 100MB and formatted as fat32). Important: don't format that partition, just put the label /boot/efi to mount on it. If you format or change filesystem to ext4 or whatever, you would loss Win 11 bootloader. Once it detects you indicated a valid partition to at least mount / and /boot/efi,  it lets you to continue; you don't even need to create swap or a different /home partition

Make sure Windows fast startup is off. It sets hibernation flag, hiding partitions from Ubuntu. Some systems require AHCI mode in UEFI settings for drives over default RAID, even if one drive. Some installs with just NVMe will use Intel® VMD which is same driver as Windows uses, just modified for Linux. Often best to have UEFI fast boot off, when changing system as it assumes no system changes, so operating system will not see changes made even on warm reboot.

Separately to remove UEFI boot entry for duplicates or uninstalled systems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

@heytham-med this was the question I referenced

Mounting the first partition as /boot or /boot/efi does not seem to change anything @luisvazquezlema. I only made a separate home partition because I want some space on my HDD for things I don't need to load quickly.

@oldfred I'm not exactly sure what you are referencing when you say AHCI mode, but I do have hibernation and fast boot off. I had no issues installing arch before.
as to your other comment, potentially found the root of the issue, that efibootmgr command fails saying  EFI variables are not supported on this system. I am sure that my system is using EFI, and I had to follow steps specific to get arch installed before.

There is some issue with either Boot-Repair, grub or dmesg. They want to see the efivars in the kernel folder when really in efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars .  If chrooting in UEFI mode you have to also manually mount efivars.  Or occasionally an ESP that is locked by vendor settings.  UEFI settings or include in chroot mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909

@oldfred could you elaborate on what the steps are to solve this issue? I tried a few of the suggestions in the thread you linked but they seem to be dealing with a more specific issue. I do not get the NVram error when running boot repair.

If you use Boot-Repair and its advanced mode which walks you thru a chroot and total reinstall of grub & also latest kernel, does that work or give the error on efivars? Or during Boot-Repair also mount efivars as above comment during the other mounts. Or a full UEFI chroot. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 which may also need mount of efivars?  & https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

@oldfred Boot repair does not seem to detect grub, all of the grub sub menus are inaccessible. I tried to follow the steps in the other question, but the chroot command fails saying "failed to run command '/bin/bash': no such file or directory". I found a similar situation in this question, and found that I was missing the /lib files as the second answer described, but I was unable to get either of the fixes they listed to work.

If Boot-Repair runs, post the link from its summary report. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
