I installed Ubuntu and erased my Windows 11 from my laptop (HDD), but the Windows files are still present in the SSD
I installed Ubuntu and erased my Windows 11 from my laptop (HDD), but the Windows files are still present in the SSD. I want to get rid of these Windows files and I want to move Ubuntu to the SSD. How do I do this?
How the partition looks right now:

GParted snapshot of SSD:


disconnect the HDD, use Ubuntu live Usb to inatall the system on the SSD and select erase the disk in the installation steps

Iinstall will not overwrite /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP, nor UEFI boot entries. Default mount of ESP in fstab prevents editing, Better to use live installer to mount & edit folders in ESP. And use efibootmgr to remove old entries in UEFI. see man efibootmgr and -b parameter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

You are not showing any Linux install, Ubuntu will not install to NTFS partitions.

If you just want to reuse the drive, delete all the partitions and reconfigure the disk for linux.  But if you delete the EFI partition, you will likely need to reinstall the linux bootloader.  Note that none of this securely deletes the files, not that this is possible on a SSD anyway.
