# Two systems, want to migrate to ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

On my laptop, I had two systems - Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
After using Ubuntu for several days I decided to fully migrate to Ubuntu.

How can I do this without losing any data? (in Ubuntu)

I understand that I need to somehow delete windows partition and extend ubuntu partition.
I am worried that I can lose some data on the way...

Can someone explain to me step by step what should I do?[image: gparted screenshot]

Comment: The only way not to lose data is to backup. So, backup all important data first, then proceed.

Comment: @Nmath thanks, already did it, everything works fine. Can you post this as an answer so I could confirm it?

Comment: Also read [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after-removing Windows partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu/1042032#1042032)

Comment: You don't have to thank me. An up-vote to the question and the answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to any partitions related to Ubuntu, you will also need to keep your EFI system partition.

You can remove the other partitions that are exclusively used by Windows.

Back up first, in case you make a mistake and remove the wrong one!