# How can I get rid of old Debian entries in my bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, disk-formatting

I had tried in vain to install Debian (which didn't work) and after that I have installed Ubuntu with LVM. Now I still have the boot entry for both OS (<kbd>F7</kbd> key on startup). Both OSes were installed by using LVM-encryption and encryption.

As suggested I installed grub-customizer, which looks like this:

[image]

No mention of Debian there. How can I get rid of this entry?

Output of `efibootmgr`:

```
nuc@nuc:~$ sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] Passwort für nuc: 
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0004,0002,0003
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* UEFI: PXE IPv4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
Boot0003* UEFI: PXE IPv6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
Boot0004* debian
```

Comment: Do you really to format the disk? You could simply install grub-customizer (`sudo apt install grub-customizer`) and from there deleting unwanted entries. If not, please edit your question with the reason and the current situation.

Comment: Can I reinstall Ubuntu LTS this way as well if the current Ubuntu is encryptet? And isn't there anything left on the harddrive of Debian (it was an encrypted installation).

Comment: My previous comment was useful only in case you want to get rid of Debian boot entry (it does not delete anything on disk). If you installed Ubuntu "over" Debian on the same partition, you can just delete such entry. But to be sure, we need to have a clearer idea on how your disk is partitioned

Comment: Can you help me to find out? I'm not sure if Ubuntu could recocnize Debian (if it was encrypteted I even if I intended to install it on the same harddrive and formated the disk during install).

Comment: You have first to tell us the history of your action. When you say "and after that I have installed Ubuntu", can you be more specific on how you performed it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I performed it over an USB iso stick by using LVM encription (both with debian and later with ubuntu).

Comment: As I have to reinstall ubuntu anyway formatting the whole thing might be faster.

Comment: Because Ubuntu seems also broken (I can't access the settings anymore, it shows the hourglass for ages).

Comment: I think you talk about efi boot menu entries, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042032/590937) might be helpful.

Comment: @dariofac: I updated the question with a screenshot of grub-customizer.

Comment: In the screenshot there is no reference of Debian to me.. As suggested by @mook765, please post also the output of `sudo efibootmgr`

Comment: @dariofac: Posted it, it's the last entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the information acquired in the comments, you only want to remove the Debian entry from the UEFI boot menu. To do that:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

The output will be, as stated in the question, like this:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0004,0002,0003
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* UEFI: PXE IPv4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
Boot0003* UEFI: PXE IPv6 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
Boot0004* debian
```

To remove the unwanted entry (`debian` in this case), run:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 4 -B
```

which will delete the following entry: `Boot0004* debian`.

After that, remove the `debian` folder from the EFI partition by running:

```
sudo rm -r /boot/efi/EFI/debian
```

Since `grub` doesn't seem to have references to `debian`, the process stops here.

At the reboot you shouldn't see `debian` anymore.

Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042032/965499) and mook765.

Comment: Thanks. Can I find out if there is still something of Debian or other ubuntuinstallations left on my harddrive if I used encryptions?