# Change grub controller in two Linux dual-boot

Tags: grub2, uefi, grub-efi, boot-partition

I had windows-10 dual booted with Ubuntu 20.04 earlier (Ubuntu was installed later).
Now I uninstalled windows and installed Manjaro 20.2.1 instead (alongside ubuntu).
I am in UEFI mode.

My partition looks somewhat as following:

[image: Partitions preview]

**/boot/efi is mounted on the EFI system partition, this was there since after ubuntu was installed with Windows.**

My /boot/efi looks as folllowing currently:

```
├── Boot
│   ├── bootx64.efi
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   └── mmx64.efi
├── Dell
│   ├── Bios
│   │   └── Recovery
│   │       ├── BIOS_CUR.RCV
│   │       └── BIOS_PRE.rcv
│   └── logs
│       ├── diags_current.xml
│       └── diags_previous.xml
├── Manjaro
│   └── grubx64.efi
├── Microsoft
│   ├── Boot
│   │   ├── BCD
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG1
│   │   ├── BCD.LOG2
│   │   ├── bg-BG
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi
│   │   ├── bootmgr.efi
│   │   ├── BOOTSTAT.DAT
│   │   ├── boot.stl
│   │   ├── cs-CZ
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── da-DK
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── de-DE
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── el-GR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── en-GB
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── en-US
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── es-ES
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── es-MX
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── et-EE
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── fi-FI
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── Fonts
│   │   │   ├── chs_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── cht_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── jpn_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── kor_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── malgun_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── malgunn_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── meiryo_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── meiryon_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── msjh_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── msjhn_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── msyh_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── msyhn_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── segmono_boot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── segoen_slboot.ttf
│   │   │   ├── segoe_slboot.ttf
│   │   │   └── wgl4_boot.ttf
│   │   ├── fr-CA
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── fr-FR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── hr-HR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── hu-HU
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── it-IT
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── ja-JP
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── kd_02_10df.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_10ec.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_1137.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_14e4.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_15b3.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_1969.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_19a2.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_1af4.dll
│   │   ├── kd_02_8086.dll
│   │   ├── kd_07_1415.dll
│   │   ├── kd_0C_8086.dll
│   │   ├── kdstub.dll
│   │   ├── ko-KR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── lt-LT
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── lv-LV
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── memtest.efi
│   │   ├── nb-NO
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── nl-NL
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── pl-PL
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── pt-BR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── pt-PT
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── qps-ploc
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── Resources
│   │   │   ├── bootres.dll
│   │   │   └── en-US
│   │   │       └── bootres.dll.mui
│   │   ├── ro-RO
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── ru-RU
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── sk-SK
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── sl-SI
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── sr-Latn-RS
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── sv-SE
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── menter image description hereemtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── tr-TR
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   ├── uk-UA
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   ├── winsipolicy.p7b
│   │   ├── zh-CN
│   │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
│   │   └── zh-TW
│   │       ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
│   │       ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
│   │       └── memtest.efi.mui
│   └── Recovery
│       ├── BCD
│       ├── BCD.LOG
│       ├── BCD.LOG1
│       └── BCD.LOG2
└── ubuntu
    ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    ├── grub.cfg
    ├── grubx64.efi
    ├── mmx64.efi
    └── shimx64.efi
```

My questions:

1. My grub menu is of Manjaro currently. I want to use the one of the ubuntu. How to do that? (sudo update-grub from ubuntu? `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep -i manjaro` from ubuntu gives nothing, I am afraid this might remove manjaro from boot options)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after custom installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: I had read that answer already before putting the question, But I have different issues if you read. I should change the title.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?