# Understanding grub and uefi bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a theoretical question about multi-booting in UEFI mode. I have Manjaro 20.2.1 installed alongside Ubuntu 20.04. Because Manjaro was installed later. Grub menu is configured by Manjaro. I want to give the control back to Ubuntu. I understand UEFI partition.

I tried to look in the internet. I found some commands:

1. update-grub
2. grub-install

I know partially about them only.
The first one to update /etc/default/grub into actual grub.
The second one to install a grub (for managing boot)

I also found some files and folder:

1. /boot/EFI (UEFI partition)
2. /boot/grub (corresponding os partition)
3. /etc/default/grub (cfg file to change grub option)

What I want to know?

1. What are the contribution of the commands and files/folders. What they actually do?
2. How to change the OS that would controls grub? (in my case from manjaro to ubuntu)

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Comment: This article pretty much answers all your questions. https://itsfoss.com/update-grub/  If you type sudo update-grub in a terminal on your Ubuntu installation it should take over grub.

Comment: A grub reinstall will reset boot order until other system does a reinstall or major update. If UEFI Ubuntu based you only have one Ubuntu entry in UEFI. But other systems use grub or name of distribution in UEFI. See this: `sudo efibootmgr -v` And you can change boot order with efibootmgr. See. `man efibootmgr` and http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr Grub install uses efibootmgr to set boot order.

Comment: Duplicate of this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311041/change-grub-controller-in-two-linux-dual-boot

Comment: @oldfred that helped got ubuntu as grub constroller, but now I can't boot into manjaro. It is showing in the boot menu, but stuck at the splash screen like [this](https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=30691.msg253131#msg253131) Don't know whether the grub install was the reason. :(

Comment: Not a duplicate. The questions although share common stuff, aim at different goals.

Comment: Does `sudo update-grub` add manjaro? If LVM or other type install, you need to mount it first.  If not copy a manjoro boot stanza into 40_custom. `sudo nano -B /etc/grub.d/40_custom` & see menu at bottom for commands. 
Then do:
`sudo update-grub`

Comment: Umm... manjaro appears in efrbootmgr, it is there in the boot menu but the moment I enter press to boot to manjaro, I am stuck at the screen. I think it is a manjaro specific issue.