# In boot manager, what are the UEFI line items and how do they relate to the regular $OS line items?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

(I realize this is not strictly ubuntu Q, other forum suggestions welcome, I figured the population on here would be knowledgable in this area).

[I'm referencing this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu).

Here's what I see after `efibootmgr`

```
sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] password for doug: 
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0003,0002
Boot0000* UEFI PC611 NVMe SK hynix 512GB NJ04N892510304S2X 1
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* UEFI PC611 NVMe SK hynix 512GB NJ04N892510304S2X 1 2
Boot0003  Pop!_OS 20.10
```

When I boot into bios menu with F12, this looks like this:
[image]

I usually boot into either 'Ubuntu' or 'Pop!_OS'.

What are the two UEFI entries? I tried booting into one and it seems it was just my Pop OS? Can I delete these UEFI entries and have just the two regularly named ones? What are these?

Comment: Most UEFI support a fallback or drive boot entry. It is at /EFI/Boot/lbootx64.efi.  With Windows, bootx64.efi is a copy of Windows efi boot file. When you install  grub it also copies shimx64.efi to be bootx64.efi. A bootx64.efi is also how all external drives boot but often different actual version of grub/shim for installer. Best to keep those drive entries as sometime you may need it. You see better details with `sudo efibootmgr -v`  and `man efibootmgr`

Comment: Waste of time deleting them unless you mount the partition and get rid of the bootx64.efi file(s). If seen by the system it will re-create an entry for them again.

Comment: Got it, so the wisdom of the crowd says to just ignore them and leave them there?

Comment: Yes they are nothing to worry about.