# How to remove Windows 11 bootloader from ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader

As I installed Ubuntu on my laptop as main OS, I wanted to remove Windows 11 completely. I deleted the windows files from gparted. I tried to remove the windows bootloader using Grub Customizer tool. It said in the tool that the windows bootloader has been removed but when I restart and go to the boot options the windows bootloader is still there. Can anyone help me?

[image: Grub Customizer Image]

And yes I saved after removing the bootloader.

Comment: You did not need grub customizer. Just remove UEFI entry with efibootmgr, and remove /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP, so grub2's os-prober has nothing to find. And then update-grub. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.