# How to use Ubuntu in SSD with formatting HHD with windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows, ssd

I had a Windows on my HDD and I installed Ubuntu to my SSD. When I turn on my laptop Windows works. I want to delete Windows on HDD and I want to use Ubuntu only, please, help me.

Comment: You can use the **GParted** utility to delete the Windows partitions and recreate them. You can use the **Disk Management** utility to format the new partitions in EXT4 format.

Comment: But before this ^^^ open UEFI settings > Boot menu and make "Ubuntu" the first boot priority. Then you can reformat everything where Windows used to be -and- use `efibootmgr` to delete the old Windows .efi entry. Please be **extremely careful, do NOT delete the ESP (EFI System Partition) that likely resides in the old HDD as well**.

Comment: Recommend that you keep a dual-boot with Windows so that you can do things like BIOS updates, or running the occasional Windows-only app.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you say *"reformat everything where Windows used to be"* but then also say *"do NOT delete the ESP"*... that sounds like an accident waiting to happen. Maybe rephrase the comment? They may also have an ESP on the SSD?

Comment: @heynnema It is indeed an accident waiting to happen since the OP decided to install a dual-boot without having the minimum knowledge required to manage OSes. My comment merely adds warnings to the previous one. Technically the ESP is not part of Windows, it's a required partition regardless of the OS or OSes that are or will be installed, for all of them and independent of each one. That said partition was likely created during the Windows installation is incidental.

Comment: After you successfully delete the Windows partitions (the C: and the Windows reserved partitions) you may want to [remove the Windows from the UEFI boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu).