# How to delete GRUB from the wrong drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have 2 SSDs: 500GB SSD splitted to 250GB of Windows 10 and 250GB of Ubuntu 20.04

The other 250GB SSD is only Windows 10.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the GRUB was somehow installed on the wrong drive (The one that does not have Ubuntu on it - it has Windows 10 on it)

I currently see 2 GRUBs: One on the wrong drive which is a working GRUB menu, and other on the drive with Ubuntu, but when I launch it, it shows me "GRUB minimal bash"

I followed this post to remove GRUB via Windows:
[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Then I tried to reinstall GRUB on the correct drive using this article:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/

But it doesn't work, after a restart, I once again get 2 GRUBs with same configuraton: 1 working GRUB on the wrong drive, and 1 "minimal bash" grub on the drive with Ubuntu.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the working GRUB on the drive with Ubuntu installed on it, and remove the GRUB from the wrong drive without Ubuntu

Comment: Use lsblk to see partitions & UUIDs & partUUIDs. Use efibootmgr to see which ESP - efi system partition is used for each boot entry. You can then delete UEFI entries and folders in ESP, that you do not need.  Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu

Comment: I changed my question completely. @oldfred sorry I was referring to another comment which was deleted

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair See Also this old bug, still an issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Use lsblk to locate the drives where grubs were installed, mount them and remove the folder `ubuntu`, then use your ubuntu bootable drive to reinstall ubuntu and point the boot partition to the right partition in the advanced options during the install.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu.
First of all, if you didn't make a specific other `/boot partition` on your 'Windows'-drive during install, don't delete any partition. In that case `Grub` is installed in the (only) EFI partition of that disk.( I have 2, so `grub` didn't mess with my windows-bootloader.)
 There are several ways to uninstall `Grub`.
1 From Windows use a program called `easybcd`. The program can be found here https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/
2 Using the command line in Windows as explained here. https://www.binaryera.com/2020/08/RemoveGrubFromWindow10.html.
3 Using a 'live'Ubuntu environment and the terminal.See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Uninstalling
This page gives you also several ways to uninstall `grub`. https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/how-do-i-remove-grub-after-uninstall-linux.html.
If you want to be absolutly sure which `grub` you uninstall, disconnect your `Ubuntu-disk` temporary. Connect it again after you uninstalled `grub` from your `Windows-disk`.