# How to remove a position from efi boot list

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I have a `HP 255` laptop and apparently one of the features it is missing is the ability to change boot order. Any time I make Ubuntu first it moves it back to second.

So on this new laptop I formatted the entire hard drive (removing windows) and installed ubuntu.

Now every time I try to boot my computer it shows error that it cannot boot windows.
I tried to use `efibootmgr` to delete the Windows entry but after reboot it is back.
I also disabled secure boot.
No matter what I do it will always place `Windows Boot Manager` on first position and fail to boot.

How am I supposed to change boot order or remove Windows from the bios boot list?

Comment: If you do not have Windows you can make an UEFI boot entry with efibootmgr that reads 'Windows Boot Manager" but actually boots using grub2's shimx64.efi. See IV: Sony, HP & others workarounds, also link to using efiboogmgr to remove entries:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win & http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file & http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager See also `man efibootmgr`. With HP change to boot order does not work but others do.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu?r=SearchResults&s=2|26.4173

Comment: I tried the efibootmgr methods and they dont work.
And modifying Windows EFI partition wont help either, since it no longer exists.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I guess I managed to put the new EFI partition in the exact same location the old one was and failed to format it, since it contained the Microsoft EFI files even though I started with a clean partition table and partitioned everything from scratch. My luck I guess. 
Replacing `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgf2.efi` with `grubx64.efi` solved the problem.