# Is this partition using windows? How can I delete it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, bootloader

I have my disk divided in two partitions and I think one of them is running windows but I don't know which one of them and how I can delete it.
In my boot menu I can see a Windows bootloader which I want to delete but don't know how, I think it may be related because on my bios settings I couldn't find any option to delete it.

Sorry if this question is dumb or if I am using incorrect terms to describe what is going on.

Disks Image:

[image]

Boot Menu:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any Windows in your computer. The fist partition is EFI System Partition (also known as ESP). This is a part of the UEFI (what used to be called BIOS). All modern computers has this partition whether it has Windows or not. Your computer won't boot without it. **Do not delete this partition!!!!**

Comment: You're talking about the second Boot Option right?

Comment: No, the comment above mentions your ESP, the only partition selected (highlighted) in your screenshoot. AGAIN, this is required. That you have a Windows bootloader there alongside Ubuntu means at some point there WERE Windows installed. Surely that entry can be deleted using the `efibootmgr` tool but probably not worth the effort and risk (deleting the wrong one will make your Ubuntu unbootable).

Comment: I agree with @ChanganAuto trying to delete the second boot option is not worth the risk. However, if you want to look into the process see [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after custom installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu). If you do want to dive into that rabbit-hole, make sure you have good backups of your valuable data, documents, pictures, videos, etc.