# Extend partition size in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have a machine with 2 partitions , one with ubuntu and the other with windows. Is possible to delete the partition of windows and then increase the partition of ubuntu ? If so, how I would do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Also read [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after custom installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu) to remove the Windows entry in the Grub boot menu.